# SQL server Update row and column in single batch

Tags: sql-server-2008

Want to achive in single batch not using dynamic SQL.

Table A:

```
Col1_ID(Primary Key), Col2_BigString
```

Table B:

```
Col1_ID( FK), Col2_Name, Col3_Value
```

`Col1_Id` is unique in `Table A` and will have corresponding multiple rows in `Table B`, the question is 
update `Col2_BigString` for each word match from `TableB.Col2_Name` replace with  `Col3_Value`.

Example - Values in `Table A` and `Table B` before the update:

Table A:

```
Col1_ID, Col2_BigString
1,       SELECT a,b,c, from xyz where a=@param1 and b in (@param2)
```

Table B:

```
Col1_ID, Col2_Name,  Col3_Value 
1,       @param1,    100
1,       @param2,    'abc','xyz'
```

Output - updated Table A:

```
1,       SELECT a,b,c, from xyz where a=100 and b in ('abc','xyz')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without using dynamic SQL.